# How to set push notification receive message target page in windows phone?

Tags: php, c#-4.0, push-notification, windows-phone, mpns

I need to set push notification receive message target page in windows phone. I can send and receive toast push notifications, but when I am click the received toast message it goes to the main page. When I click the toast message I need the app to open in the target page. Please let me know why I am facing in this issue and what is wrong in my code.

My code is given below:

C# Receive Target page:

```
 void PushChannel_ShellToastNotificationReceived(object sender, NotificationEventArgs e)
    {
        StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder();
        string relativeUri = string.Empty;

        message.AppendFormat("Received Toast {0}:\n", DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString());

        // Parse out the information that was part of the message.
        foreach (string key in e.Collection.Keys)
        {
            message.AppendFormat("{0}: {1}\n", key, e.Collection[key]);

            if (string.Compare(
                key,
                "wp:Param",
                System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                System.Globalization.CompareOptions.IgnoreCase) == 0)
            {
                relativeUri = e.Collection[key];

            }
        }

        // Display a dialog of all the fields in the toast.
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => MessageBox.Show(message.ToString()));

    }
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

        //  If we navigated to this page
        // from the MainPage, the DefaultTitle parameter will be "FromMain".  If we navigated here
        // when the secondary Tile was tapped, the parameter will be "FromTile".
        textBlockFrom.Text = "Navigated here from " + this.NavigationContext.QueryString["NavigatedFrom"];

    }
```

I am using PHP code for sending the push notifications:

```
  <?php 
  final class WindowsPhonePushDelay
  {

   const Immediate=0;

   private function __construct(){}
 }

 class WindowsPhonePushNotification
 {
  private $notif_url = '';

  function WindowsPhonePushNotification($notif_url)
  {
     $this->notif_url = $notif_url;
  }
  public function push($target,$message,$notif_url)
  {

   // Create the toast message
   $toastMessage = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>" .
            "<wp:Notification xmlns:wp=\"WPNotification\">" .
               "<wp:Toast>" .
                    "<wp:Text1>" . "SendToast" . "</wp:Text1>" .
                    "<wp:Text2>" . $message . "</wp:Text2>" .
                    "<wp:Param>/Receive.xaml?NavigatedFrom=Toast Notification</wp:Param>" .
                    "</wp:Toast> " .
            "</wp:Notification>";

  // Create request to send
     $r = curl_init();
     curl_setopt($r, CURLOPT_URL,$notif_url);
     curl_setopt($r, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
     curl_setopt($r, CURLOPT_POST, true);
     curl_setopt($r, CURLOPT_HEADER, true); 

  // add headers
     $httpHeaders=array('Content-type: text/xml; charset=utf-8', 'X-WindowsPhone-Target: toast',
                'Accept: application/*', 'X-NotificationClass: 2','Content-Length:'.strlen($toastMessage));
  curl_setopt($r, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $httpHeaders);

  // add message
  curl_setopt($r, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $toastMessage);

  // execute request
  $output = curl_exec($r);
  curl_close($r);

   }
}

?>
```

I need output as in the image below

[image]

Comment: What version of Windows Phone are you using? The `Param` parameter is not supported in Windows Phone 7.

Comment: I am using Windows Phone 8 version

Answer (score 0):

The wp:param that's part of the toast notification's payload should be a uri. Therefore it should also be encoded as one. In the example that you're providing there's a space in the payload, that might be causing problems. Could you try formatting it like this?

```
  "<wp:Param>/Receive.xaml?NavigatedFrom=Toast%20Notification</wp:Param>" .
```

Also make sure that Receive.xaml is indeed in the root of your package.

Comment: Can you please verify the generated XML for the push notification? Could you generate the XML using your code and share it so we can confirm the format is right? Thanks!

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>